# Getting error while activating appplication in xcuitest script

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I am running xcuitest script where I am running the command

Command :

```
AppsInformation.Apps.viewer.activate()
```

and Getting error:

> "Unable to update application state promptly for Application 'com.mac.macan.acnc.mac'."

Please suggest for this

Comment: I have no idea what kind of XCUITest is this supposed to be, but have you tried using  `launch()` instead of `activate()`?